# RewriteCond to change displayed host, but not server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vhosts

Typing out the title to this leads me to believe this might not be possible due to security concerns, but I will ask anyway.  I have shortcode support running on my server, lets call it `xx.yy`

I want it so when a user sends a request to `xx.yy`, it just changes the displayed host to another valid domain running on the same box.

I have this so far (lets the server know to accept requests from `xx.yy`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^.*xx.yy [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:<PORT_OMITTED>%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^.*mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:<PORT_OMITTED>%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
```

It works, and it directs the traffic into my app, but the url says `http://xx.yy` when I would rather it say `http://mysite.com`

I know i could redirect to `http://mysite.com` instead of `127.0.0.1`, but I have 4 parallel boxes of `mysite.com` and going back out to DNS to maybe go to another box seems like a waste when I am already here.  Also, I am not sure how POST requests would work like that.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mysite.com` is on the same box, and DNS is pointing there, just put `R=301` in `[P,QSA,L]`

Example

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OldDomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.OldDomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.NewDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

From http://www.liewcf.com/redirect-webpages-to-another-domain-538/

Other than that, though there's no way for good reasons to do what you are asking. Imagine if someone could link to legitwebsite.com, but have it get sent to evilempire.com.

It'd be chaos, that's what.

Comment: Makes sense, I never thought about it this way until I read back what I had written for the title